# Elasticsearch 2.x Not working with Spring boot 1.2.5

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

Hi Friends i have installed elastic search `1.4.5` and i am using spring boot `1.2.5` . With this setup everything is working fine. Dependencies included for elasticsearch in my pom file is:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now we know elasticsearch upgraded and the latest version is of 2.x series.
I have installed elasticsearch `2.3.1` as soon as i started my spring boot application it gives me warnings

```
[2016-04-25 11:48:27,263][WARN ][transport.netty          ] [Katie Power] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x70aad8aa, /127.0.0.1:41327 => /127.0.0.1:9300]], closing connection
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Message not fully read (request) for requestId [6], action [cluster/nodes/info], readerIndex [39] vs expected [57]; resetting
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:121)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.OpenChannelsHandler.handleUpstream(OpenChannelsHandler.java:75)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2016-04-25 11:48:49,630][WARN ][cluster.routing.allocation.decider] [Katie Power] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [-jqppXgpTx2f6iNLg520Gg][Katie Power][/home/mohdqasim/Downloads/elasticsearch-2.3.1/data/qasimelasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 317.2mb[1.7%], shards will be relocated away from this node
[2016-04-25 11:49:19,631][WARN ][cluster.routing.allocation.decider] [Katie Power] high disk watermark [90%] exceeded on [-jqppXgpTx2f6iNLg520Gg][Katie Power][/home/mohdqasim/Downloads/elasticsearch-2.3.1/data/qasimelasticsearch/nodes/0] free: 317.2mb[1.7%], shards will be relocated away from this node
```

and my elasticserch is not updated with indexes which i defined in my application.

I have search for a long time on google but could not found its solution. 
Can some help me please!

Answer (score 3):

That's because Spring Boot currently works with `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` 1.3.3-RELEASE and not yet with the 2.0.0-RELEASE which supports ES 2.x.

Since you have Spring Boot 1.2.5, it's an even older version that won't support ES 2.x

Comment: Did this help? Do you need more info?

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot version `1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` supports ES 2.x now. Install it by this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html